# Eliminating duplicate code AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In a CRUD scenario it’s very common to load a list of records, then reload it after adding a new record. You’ll end up with something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('UsersController', function($scope,UserService)   {
  UserService.all().then(function(users) {
  $scope.users = users;
};

$scope.addUser = function(userData) { 
  UserService.add(userData).then(function() {
    UserService.all().then(function(users) {
      $scope.users = users;
    };
  };
};
```

});

As you can see I have UserService.all() called twice even in addUser scope which I think this is a wrong aproach.

How would I eliminate this kind of duplicate code..

I have heard using state Resolve would eliminate such duplicate code, what is your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is really not specific to angular, you would approach this as you would with any kind of code. You could wrap the duplicate code in another method and call that instead:

```
$scope.reloadUsers=function(){
  UserService.all().then(function(users) {
      $scope.users = users;
  };
};
```

And then call `$scope.reloadUsers()` instead of calling `UserService.all()`.

Comment: @Mizlul Resolve will help you to always have something available (like the list of users) by the time the controller is loaded. I don't think it will help you in this particular instance as you need to reload the list of users made available by resolve (after the controller is loaded) by calling `UserService.add(userData)`, where as the code inside resolve will only run once.